# Getting the version of and .apk file without installing

Tags: javascript, android, apk, cordova-plugins

I've problem regarding my auto update of my application. The problem is that i cannot figure out how to check version of an .apk file with out installing it.

Are there any possible ways with javascript to check the version of an .apk file without installing it? Even better is it possible to check the version before even downloading it?

My code to download and promt installation is as following

```
        downloadApkAndroid('urlToAPK');
    function downloadApkAndroid(data) {
        var fileURL = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "fileName.apk"; 
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI(data);
        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            fileURL,
            function (entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                promptForUpdateAndroid(entry);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            },
            false,
            {

            }
        );
    }
    /*
     * Uses webintent plugin
     */
    function promptForUpdateAndroid(entry) {
        window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
            action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
            url: entry.toURL(),
            type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
        },
            function () {
            },
            function () {
                alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.' + entry.fullPath);
                console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent. URL: " + entry.fullPath);
            }
        );
    }
```

As the code is now, it downloads the .apk file even though it is the same as the installed version. I would like to know how if I can check the version of the .apk file before downloading or atleast before installing.

Comment: I suggest write the version to a file in your server, and check it while downloading.

Comment: Thats a way to do it, I just think that it would be much easier if i did not had to create and extra file with the version number

Comment: that will not easy, you need unzip apk, find manifest file, uncompress the xml, parse the xml, find the version. lots of code

Comment: You right, I've implemented your suggestion and it works fine, thanks for your help!